# Get mail signature programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How I can get the mail signature (like "sent from my iphone") programmatically.

Comment: Are you trying to get the default signature from the iPhone's settings or are you trying to get the signature from the bottom of an email message?

Answer (score 3):

A signature is simply some constant text automatically added to the end of a message by the software that sent the email. There is no way to programmatically distinguish it from the rest of the message.

Answer (score 3):

There was a tradition where newsgroup and email signatures would begin with a line starting with two dashes to allow for easy automated filtering, but this seems to have fallen by the wayside as use of the internet expanded and certainly is not observed by the automated signatures added by most devices.

Realistically, if you want to filter away the automated signatures, the best thing to do would be to build a list of them and then use that list to recognize them.  This won't work for arbitrary signatures, though, only ones on your list.

Comment: Not dead yet, I still use this convention!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no publicly documented way to do this in the iOS SDK.

Comment: ^- this. The apps that allow users to create their own signature use the MessageUI framework to draft & send emails from within the app - and, hence, insert a custom signature into the email before you send it.